# Rotate image for 180 degrees with fixed aspect ration

Tags: photoeditorsdk

I have a PhotoEditorSDK for android 5.0.7. When the image editing is configured to use fixed aspect ratio like this

```
settings.getConfig().setAspects(new CropAspectConfig(4, 3));
```

it is not possible to rotate the image at all. I can understand why I cannot rotate it for +- 90 degrees - it will break the aspect ratio. But is there any legal possibility (maybe via extension of TransformEditorTool to make rotation happen in 180 degrees steps, so that aspect is preserved. Unfortunately I could not find a suitable place in code where I can influece the behavior. changeOrientationCW and changeOrientationCCW methods in TransformEditorTool look promising, but get never called when clicking on rotate button even when it is allowed to do. Any suggestions

Comment: If they have flip and reflect functions you can combine them to rotate 180 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Bug, we are currently fixing this problem. A Bug fix should be available next week.